# PID slider joint in gazebo 1.3 / 1.5

Tags: gazebo-tutorial, gazebo-1.5, gazebo-1.3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I tried to follow the [tutorial for the pid joint](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/intermediate/pid_control_joint). With ROS groovy and Gazebo 1.3.
If I add the build dir to the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and run using: rosrun gazebo gazebo -u ../pid_joints.world It can find the plugin..

```
Error [Plugin.hh:126] Failed to load plugin libpid_joints.so: libpid_joints.so
```

I also tried it using the standalone Gazebo 1.5. Then the box is spawned but Gazebo crashes as I push the play button.

```
gazebo: symbol lookup error: /home/user/gazebo_pid_joints/build/libpid_joints.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6gazebo6common7Console8InstanceEv
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2161/pid-slider-joint-in-gazebo-1.3-/-1.5/) by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-04-01**:
also could you change the questions title because it is not very relevant to the errors

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-05-20**:
hello, so did you get it to work? for the second issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

For the **first issue** using gazebo 1.3 most probably you are missing the GAZEBO PATHS to the plugin.

Here is an example how to add yout package plugin library:

```
$ export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/<path>/your_package/lib:${GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH}
```

For the **second issue** when you run your code with gazebo 1.5, this might appear because your code could be built against the gazebo 1.3 libraries from groovy, that's why you get that error when you run the plugin.

To avoid this when you build your package you should comment out **`<depend package="gazebo"/>`** line from your **`manifest.xml`** file. Afterwards in the **`CMakeLists.txt`** file add the following lines to link against yout gazebo 1.5 libraries:

```
## link to gazebo libraries 
include (FindPkgConfig)
if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
  pkg_check_modules(GAZEBO gazebo)
endif()
include_directories(${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on 2013-04-01**:
Thanks for your response! The build dir with the libpid_joints.so is both in the gazebo and ros path. But that does not help. I builded these not as a ros package, will try that later.